# VS XAML Editor Keyboard Shortcut to Select Parent Element

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, keyboard-shortcuts

Given the following XAML

```
<Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        ...
    </Rectangle.Fill>
    ...
</Rectangle>
```

Assuming the edit caret is blinking over the Rectangle.Fill element.

Is there a keyboard shortcut which will select the entire parent Rectangle element (including all nested elements)?

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Alt+]`

It's not perfect since it doesn't capture the last `>`, but it's better than nothing.

Also you have to place the caret right after the opening `<`